# want to fetch imap body from server

Tags: php, email

I am trying to fetch the email body from my server but for some reason, I can only fetch it for only selected emails most of them show us blank. here is my code I am showing the email in a modal. I am getting the message-id from the webpage it's a little out of sequence so I am adding +1 in the message-id. for security reasons, I am hiding the hostname and mailbox but I can assure you it's correct.

```
if (isset($_POST['getemail'])) {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $mailbox="";$username="";$password="";$inboxemail="";
        $hostname = '{mail.xxxxxxxxx.com:123/novalidate-cert/pop3/ssl}INBOX';
        $mailbox = "{mail.xxxxxxxxxx.com:123/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";
        $username = $_POST['kmail'];
        $password = $_POST['kpass'];
    
    $mbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Tiriyo: ' . imap_last_error());
    $MC=imap_check($mbox);
    $MN=$MC->Nmsgs;
    $overview=imap_fetch_overview($mbox,"1:$MN",0);
    $size=sizeof($overview);
    $val=$overview[$_POST['id']];
    $msg=$val->msgno;
    $id=intval($_POST['id'])+1;
    $message = imap_fetchbody($mbox,$id,1.2);
    $message=quoted_printable_decode($message);
    $from=$val->from;
    $date=$val->date;
    $subj=$val->subject;
    $inboxemail.= ' <div class="modal-header border-bottom">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="LoginForm-title"style=" color:#000;">'.$subj.'</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" style=" color:#000;" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    
                    </div>
                    <hr style="margin:0%;">
                    <div class="modal-body p-0">
                    <div class="p-3 border-bottom">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                <img src="assets/images/client/05.jpg" class="avatar avatar-md-sm rounded-circle border shadow" alt="">
                                <div class="flex-1 ms-2">
                                    <span class="d-block" id="ename"></span>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle p-0 text-muted small fw-normal" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" id="infrom" aria-expanded="false">'.$from.'</button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dd-menu bg-white shadow border-0 mt-2 p-3 mb-0">
                                            <li class="text-muted small">From: <small class="text-dark" id="in1from">'.$from.'</small></li>
                                            <li class="text-muted small">To: <small class="text-dark" id="in1to">'.$_POST['kmail'].'</small></li>
                                            <li class="text-muted small">Cc: <small class="text-dark" id="in1cc"></small></li>
                                            <li class="text-muted small" id="bccdiv" style="display:none;">Bcc: <small class="text-dark" id="in1bcc"></small></li>
                                            <li class="text-muted small">Date: <small class="text-dark" id="in1date">'.$date.'</small></li>
                                        </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-icon btn-sm btn-pills btn-soft-light" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Reply"><i class="ti ti-arrow-back-up"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-icon btn-sm btn-pills btn-soft-light" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Forward"><i class="ti ti-arrow-forward-up"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr style="margin:0%;">
                    <div class="p-3 border-bottom" id="inbody"><p>
                        '.$message.'</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="p-3">
                        <p class="text-muted mb-0">Click here to <a href="#!" class="text-primary">Reply</a> or <a href="#!" class="text-primary">Forward</a></p>
                    </div>
                    </div>';
      
    imap_close($mbox);
    
    $arr = array('error' => FALSE, 'msg' => $msg, 'inboxemail' => $inboxemail );
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Comment: it looks like you're only fetching section `1.2` from the email bodies. There's no guarantee that the body you're looking for is in that section.

Comment: if I try this $message = imap_fetchbody($mbox,$id,1,1.2); it shows the body in text/plain format if I change the third parameter to 1.2 the message goes away, can u please help me I have a dead line tomorrow and i am bit noob in PHP

Comment: You likely need to loop through every section until you get the one you want

Comment: Also bear in mind that some emails are not formatted as multipart

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the mail body is encoded as quoted_printable? Some servers or senders automatically encode data to base64 format.

I can recommend this library instead of using imap_open directly.https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap